# Hang up without any output while convert model with DistributedDataParallel

Tags: gpu, torch

I have already test the same code on 1 node 2GPU. But the issue happens on 2 nodes * 2 GPU.

The python code shown as follows:

```py
import torch.distributed as dist
from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
rank = int(os.environ["RANK"])
local_rank = int(os.environ["LOCAL_RANK"])
world_size = int(os.environ["WORLD_SIZE"])
dist.init_process_group(backend=backend)
device = torch.device("cuda:{}".format(local_rank))
model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)  # copy model from cpu to gpu
# [*] using DistributedDataParallel
# model = DDP(model, device_ids=[local_rank], output_device=local_rank, broadcast_buffers=False, find_unused_parameters=True)  # [*] DDP(...)
print('DDP starting')
model = DDP(model, broadcast_buffers=False, find_unused_parameters=True) 
print('DDP ending')
```

The script on master node:

```bash
NCCL_P2P_DISABLE=1\
TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=True NCCL_DEBUG=INFO \
NCCL_DEBUG_SUBSYS=INIT,GRAPH NCCL_TOPO_DUMP_FILE=topo.xml \
    python -m torch.distributed.launch \
        --nproc_per_node 2 --nnodes 2 --node_rank 0 \
        --master_addr="8.0.0.215" --master_port=8002 \
        single-machine-and-multi-GPU-DistributedDataParallel-launch.py
```

The script on worker node:

```bash
NCCL_P2P_DISABLE=1\
TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=True NCCL_DEBUG=INFO \
NCCL_DEBUG_SUBSYS=INIT,GRAPH NCCL_TOPO_DUMP_FILE=topo.xml \
    python -m torch.distributed.launch \
        --nproc_per_node 2 --nnodes 2 --node_rank 1 \
        --master_addr="8.0.0.215" --master_port=8002 \
        single-machine-and-multi-GPU-DistributedDataParallel-launch.py
```

The terminal output for master hang up after:

```bash
(prompt) [root@gpu215 pytorch-multi-GPU-training-tutorial]# bash script/mult_master.sh 
/root/miniconda3/envs/prompt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py:181: FutureWarning: The module torch.distributed.launch is deprecated
and will be removed in future. Use torchrun.
Note that --use-env is set by default in torchrun.
If your script expects `--local-rank` argument to be set, please
change it to read from `os.environ['LOCAL_RANK']` instead. See 
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#launch-utility for 
further instructions

  warnings.warn(
WARNING:torch.distributed.run:
*****************************************
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed. 
*****************************************
DDP starting
DDP starting
gpu215:14096:14096 [0] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using ens6f0:8.0.0.215<0>
gpu215:14096:14096 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin : No plugin found (libnccl-net.so), using internal implementation
gpu215:14096:14096 [0] NCCL INFO cudaDriverVersion 12010
NCCL version 2.14.3+cuda11.7
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO NET/IB : No device found.
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Socket : Using [0]ens6f0:8.0.0.215<0>
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Using network Socket
gpu215:14097:14097 [1] NCCL INFO cudaDriverVersion 12010
gpu215:14097:14097 [1] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using ens6f0:8.0.0.215<0>
gpu215:14097:14097 [1] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin : No plugin found (libnccl-net.so), using internal implementation
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO NET/IB : No device found.
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO NET/Socket : Using [0]ens6f0:8.0.0.215<0>
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Using network Socket
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO NCCL_P2P_LEVEL set by environment to LOC
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO === System : maxBw 1.2 totalBw 24.0 ===
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO CPU/2 (1/0/-1)
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/7
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/41000 (0)
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO CPU/6 (1/0/-1)
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/7
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/C1000 (1)
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO CPU/7 (1/0/-1)
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO + PCI[3.0] - NIC/E1000
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO              + NET[1.2] - NET/0 (0/0/1.250000)
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO ==========================================
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO GPU/41000 :GPU/41000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) GPU/C1000 (3/24.000000/SYS) CPU/2 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/6 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/7 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO GPU/C1000 :GPU/41000 (3/24.000000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) CPU/2 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/6 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/7 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO NET/0 :GPU/41000 (4/1.250000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (4/1.250000/SYS) CPU/2 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/6 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/7 (2/1.250000/PHB) NET/0 (0/5000.000000/LOC) 
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Setting affinity for GPU 1 to ff0000,00000000,00ff0000,00000000
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Pattern 4, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 1.200000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/0 GPU/1 NET/0
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Pattern 1, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 2.400000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/0 GPU/1 NET/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Pattern 3, crossNic 0, nChannels 0, bw 0.000000/0.000000, type NVL/PIX, sameChannels 1
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO NCCL_P2P_LEVEL set by environment to LOC
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO === System : maxBw 1.2 totalBw 24.0 ===
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO CPU/2 (1/0/-1)
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/7
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/41000 (0)
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO CPU/6 (1/0/-1)
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/7
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/C1000 (1)
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO CPU/7 (1/0/-1)
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO + PCI[3.0] - NIC/E1000
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO              + NET[1.2] - NET/0 (0/0/1.250000)
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO ==========================================
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO GPU/41000 :GPU/41000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) GPU/C1000 (3/24.000000/SYS) CPU/2 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/6 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/7 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO GPU/C1000 :GPU/41000 (3/24.000000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) CPU/2 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/6 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/7 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO NET/0 :GPU/41000 (4/1.250000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (4/1.250000/SYS) CPU/2 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/6 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/7 (2/1.250000/PHB) NET/0 (0/5000.000000/LOC) 
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Setting affinity for GPU 0 to ff0000,00000000,00ff0000
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Pattern 4, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 1.200000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/0 GPU/1 NET/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Pattern 1, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 2.400000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/0 GPU/1 NET/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Pattern 3, crossNic 0, nChannels 0, bw 0.000000/0.000000, type NVL/PIX, sameChannels 1
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Tree 0 : 0 -> 1 -> -1/-1/-1
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Tree 1 : 0 -> 1 -> -1/-1/-1
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Ring 00 : 0 -> 1 -> 2
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Tree 0 : -1 -> 0 -> 1/2/-1
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Ring 01 : 0 -> 1 -> 2
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Tree 1 : 2 -> 0 -> 1/-1/-1
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Trees [0] -1/-1/-1->1->0 [1] -1/-1/-1->1->0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/02 :    0   1   2   3
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/02 :    0   1   2   3
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Ring 00 : 3 -> 0 -> 1
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Ring 01 : 3 -> 0 -> 1
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Trees [0] 1/2/-1->0->-1 [1] 1/-1/-1->0->2
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 3[c1000] -> 0[41000] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 1[c1000] -> 2[41000] [send] via NET/Socket/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 3[c1000] -> 0[41000] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 0[41000] -> 1[c1000] via SHM/direct/direct
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 0[41000] -> 1[c1000] via SHM/direct/direct
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 1[c1000] -> 2[41000] [send] via NET/Socket/0
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Connected all rings
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 1[c1000] -> 0[41000] via SHM/direct/direct
gpu215:14097:14208 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 1[c1000] -> 0[41000] via SHM/direct/direct
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Connected all rings
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 2[41000] -> 0[41000] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 2[41000] -> 0[41000] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 0[41000] -> 2[41000] [send] via NET/Socket/0
gpu215:14096:14191 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 0[41000] -> 2[41000] [send] via NET/Socket/0
```

The terminal output for worker node:

```bash
(prompt) [root@gpu216 pytorch-multi-GPU-training-tutorial]# bash script/mult_worker.sh 
/root/miniconda3/envs/prompt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py:181: FutureWarning: The module torch.distributed.launch is deprecated
and will be removed in future. Use torchrun.
Note that --use-env is set by default in torchrun.
If your script expects `--local-rank` argument to be set, please
change it to read from `os.environ['LOCAL_RANK']` instead. See 
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#launch-utility for 
further instructions

  warnings.warn(
WARNING:torch.distributed.run:
*****************************************
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed. 
*****************************************
DDP starting
DDP starting
gpu216:10445:10445 [0] NCCL INFO cudaDriverVersion 12010
gpu216:10445:10445 [0] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using ens16f0:8.0.0.216<0>
gpu216:10445:10445 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin : No plugin found (libnccl-net.so), using internal implementation
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO NET/IB : Using [0]mlx5_0:1/RoCE [RO]; OOB ens16f0:8.0.0.216<0>
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Using network IB
gpu216:10446:10446 [1] NCCL INFO cudaDriverVersion 12010
gpu216:10446:10446 [1] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using ens16f0:8.0.0.216<0>
gpu216:10446:10446 [1] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin : No plugin found (libnccl-net.so), using internal implementation
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO NET/IB : Using [0]mlx5_0:1/RoCE [RO]; OOB ens16f0:8.0.0.216<0>
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Using network IB
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO NCCL_P2P_LEVEL set by environment to LOC
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO === System : maxBw 1.2 totalBw 24.0 ===
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO CPU/2 (1/0/-1)
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/41000 (2)
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO CPU/6 (1/0/-1)
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/C1000 (3)
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO CPU/0 (1/0/-1)
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO + PCI[6.0] - NIC/1000
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO              + NET[1.2] - NET/0 (4e4ed33d194e5074/1/1.250000)
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO ==========================================
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO GPU/41000 :GPU/41000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) GPU/C1000 (3/24.000000/SYS) CPU/2 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/6 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/0 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO GPU/C1000 :GPU/41000 (3/24.000000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) CPU/2 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/6 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/0 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO NET/0 :GPU/41000 (4/1.250000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (4/1.250000/SYS) CPU/2 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/6 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/0 (2/1.250000/PHB) NET/0 (0/5000.000000/LOC) 
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Setting affinity for GPU 1 to ff0000,00000000,00ff0000,00000000
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO KV Convert to int : could not find value of 'HygonGenuine' in dictionary, falling back to 0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Pattern 4, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 1.200000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/2 GPU/3 NET/0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Pattern 1, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 2.400000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/2 GPU/3 NET/0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Pattern 3, crossNic 0, nChannels 0, bw 0.000000/0.000000, type NVL/PIX, sameChannels 1
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO NCCL_P2P_LEVEL set by environment to LOC
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO === System : maxBw 1.2 totalBw 24.0 ===
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO CPU/2 (1/0/-1)
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/41000 (2)
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO CPU/6 (1/0/-1)
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + PCI[24.0] - GPU/C1000 (3)
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO CPU/0 (1/0/-1)
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/2
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + SYS[5000.0] - CPU/6
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO + PCI[6.0] - NIC/1000
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO              + NET[1.2] - NET/0 (4e4ed33d194e5074/1/1.250000)
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO ==========================================
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO GPU/41000 :GPU/41000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) GPU/C1000 (3/24.000000/SYS) CPU/2 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/6 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/0 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO GPU/C1000 :GPU/41000 (3/24.000000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (0/5000.000000/LOC) CPU/2 (2/24.000000/SYS) CPU/6 (1/24.000000/PHB) CPU/0 (2/24.000000/SYS) NET/0 (4/1.250000/SYS) 
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO NET/0 :GPU/41000 (4/1.250000/SYS) GPU/C1000 (4/1.250000/SYS) CPU/2 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/6 (3/1.250000/SYS) CPU/0 (2/1.250000/PHB) NET/0 (0/5000.000000/LOC) 
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Setting affinity for GPU 0 to ff0000,00000000,00ff0000
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Pattern 4, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 1.200000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/2 GPU/3 NET/0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Pattern 1, crossNic 0, nChannels 1, bw 2.400000/1.200000, type SYS/SYS, sameChannels 1
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO  0 : NET/0 GPU/2 GPU/3 NET/0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Pattern 3, crossNic 0, nChannels 0, bw 0.000000/0.000000, type NVL/PIX, sameChannels 1
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Tree 0 : 2 -> 3 -> -1/-1/-1
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Tree 0 : 0 -> 2 -> 3/-1/-1
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Tree 1 : 2 -> 3 -> -1/-1/-1
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Tree 1 : -1 -> 2 -> 3/0/-1
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Ring 00 : 2 -> 3 -> 0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Ring 00 : 1 -> 2 -> 3
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Ring 01 : 2 -> 3 -> 0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Ring 01 : 1 -> 2 -> 3
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Trees [0] -1/-1/-1->3->2 [1] -1/-1/-1->3->2
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Trees [0] 3/-1/-1->2->0 [1] 3/0/-1->2->-1
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 1[c1000] -> 2[41000] [receive] via NET/IB/0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 3[c1000] -> 0[41000] [send] via NET/IB/0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 1[c1000] -> 2[41000] [receive] via NET/IB/0
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 2[41000] -> 3[c1000] via SHM/direct/direct
gpu216:10445:10525 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 2[41000] -> 3[c1000] via SHM/direct/direct
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 3[c1000] -> 0[41000] [send] via NET/IB/0
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Connected all rings
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 00 : 3[c1000] -> 2[41000] via SHM/direct/direct
gpu216:10446:10536 [1] NCCL INFO Channel 01 : 3[c1000] -> 2[41000] via SHM/direct/direct
```

As you can see, The output hang up after

```py
print('DDP starting')
```

According to the nvidia-smi and top, the model has already been load into 4gpus. And the cpu utility is greater than 100%.
nvidia-smi terminal output:

```bash
Every 1.0s: nvidia-smi                                        gpu216: Thu Apr 13 15:02:28 2023

Thu Apr 13 15:02:29 2023
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.30.02              Driver Version: 530.30.02    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A800 80GB PCIe           Off| 00000000:41:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   33C    P0               66W / 300W|   1845MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A800 80GB PCIe           Off| 00000000:C1:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P0               63W / 300W|    943MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3948      G   /usr/libexec/Xorg                             4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10445      C   ...t/miniconda3/envs/prompt/bin/python      936MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10446      C   ...t/miniconda3/envs/prompt/bin/python      902MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      3948      G   /usr/libexec/Xorg                             4MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     10446      C   ...t/miniconda3/envs/prompt/bin/python      936MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

top terminal output:

```bash
top - 15:04:49 up 43 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.28, 4.29, 4.10Tasks: 1428 total,   4 running, 1424 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.0 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 stMiB Mem : 128545.8 total, 115598.2 free,   8534.6 used,   4412.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used. 118872.3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                 10445 root      20   0   14.1g   2.0g 474996 R 300.3   1.6 106:59.50 python                
  10446 root      20   0   16.5g   2.6g 581368 R 100.3   2.0  35:45.30 python                   4032 root      20   0  124848  22064   6520 S   2.6   0.0   0:21.90 pmdalinux             
   5645 root      20   0  969240  94652  37984 S   1.3   0.1   0:09.48 node                     6911 root      20   0  276884   6648   4096 R   1.3   0.0   0:32.89 top                   
   5755 root      20   0 1080092 193328  43860 S   1.0   0.1   0:15.05 node                  
   3183 root      20   0  125816   6444   4856 S   0.7   0.0   0:05.43 irqbalance            
   3374 root      20   0  780008  46344  19136 S   0.7   0.0   0:17.67 tuned                 
   4025 root      20   0  115124  12768   6864 S   0.7   0.0   0:11.23 pmdaproc
```

So... what happened? Anything I can do for checking this?